# Remove user from Asana assignee list

Tags: asana

Removing a user from a workspace is easy enough, but how do you remove them from the assignee list? I've got a bunch of clients and ex-employees that would be nice not to have to scroll through.

Here's a screenshot of the assignee list: http://spig.io/image/3n2Q0G1x3y3d

Comment: Do you mean the auto-complete pop-up? Where are you scrolling through them specifically?

Comment: Also: not really a programming question, so likely to be deleted real soon. Probably a better fit for... I'm not sure, SuperUser? than StackOverflow.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show where I'm finding them. And yes, not a programming question, so if this gets deleted so be it. I'll repost there.

Answer (score 0):

If they're still in the assignee autocomplete, odds are they somehow haven't been removed from the workspace entirely. They may still be guests of the workspace or something. Best to get in touch with [support](https://asana.com/support) and include your workspace ID so they can find out what relation the users in question have with your workspace and why they're still showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Following [agnoster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254896/agnoster)'s advice to contact support, Josh from Asana replied that:

> When removing a Member from a Team, if you would like to also remove
>   them from the Organization, you must deprovision them:
>   http://asana.com/guide/basics/removing#gl-deprovision

I'm not sure if this is a new option or not but following his advice I was able to remove users from the assignee list.